# Connecting AWS RDS in VPC with Google Cloud Composer

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to build a google cloud composer connecting to AWS RDS to do schedule ELT jobs. However, the RDS is in private subnet of VPC, and the connection is allowed by a white listing IP in Security Group.

I have tried to create a NAT gateway for google kubernetes engine, but I couldn't find any ways to use the NAT gateway in google cloud composer. Is it possible to make the workers in google cloud composer be created in a range of public ip?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my colleague find the problem is not the ip address of pods. The problem is the DNS in GCP cannot forward the connection from pods to AWS.

And therefore, the solution is create an instance in AWS which allows Cloud DNS in GCP to connect, and set the forwarding rules of "amazonaws.com" to the IP address to the instance. Then the connection from pods will be forwarded to AWS if the host name is "amazonaws.com".

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the solution? I didn't fully understand "The problem is the DNS in GCP cannot forward the connection from pods to AWS". I am running into similar problem, I am able to connect RDS from the cloud composer gke cluster node but not from the pods running airflow workers.